# List main menu links

Tags: navigation

I need a list of main menu item links to display on a page (sort of a sitemap). 
How would I accomplish this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
   print theme('links__menu_main_page', array('links' => $menu));
```

Write This code where you want to display menu.

Or you can assign menu block to a region and can call that region like this

```
print render($page['menu_block']);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is good as well, but I get only the top level items, is there any way to get an array of all top level items and it's children?

Comment: Print render(menu_block_view('main-menu'))

Answer (score 1):

Go to `admin/structure/block` and configure the Main Menu block

[image]

You want to go further you can Install [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module

> So… have you ever used the Main and Secondary menu links feature on your theme and wondered “how the hell do I display any menu items deeper than that?”
>
> Well, that’s what this module does. It provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu. And more!